# C# send video frame

Tags: c#, video, udp, frame

I would like to send video frames using UDP connection from the client to server.

How do I get the video frame from my webcam? Do I need to save every frame to my computer and from there send it to the server? If i run on 30fps which means i need to save 30 video frames every second on my computer? Or can i directly send from the video frames i obtained from the webcam?

Currently i am only able to turn on the webcam and display the video onto the client's UI with the use of the Aforge library.

I have looked through many different threads and i didn't seem to benefit from them as I have a weak foundation in C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a video compression scheme.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, in order to do video streaming, i need to send every frame to the server right? Then on the server side, it needs to  be constantly displaying the latest frame received on a picture box? So the video compression scheme you meant which is to compress the frames so that it will be smaller in size? @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the webcam video frame by frame using the [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library (it's availabe as DirectShowLib over NuGet). There's a nice DxSnap sample that shows how to get still images. The hardest part is to get your head around the DirectShow API which may look foreign if you "have a weak foundation in C#" and/or haven't dealt with [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) code before.

And depending on the resolution, the frame rate may top way below 30 fps due to performance/bandwidth limitations. If you need a high frame rate at a decent resolution, you may have to encode the video first using some bitrate-efficient encoder.

Both options - frame by frame and video encoding - are possible using this library (although the latter may not be easy to pass through UDP). You just need to set up a proper graph. [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) may be of great help with this, especially because it can generate C# code of your graph for DirectShow.NET (a little annoyance here is that you can't copy the code to the clipboard unless you purchase the app).

Basically, if you're certain about sending every frame then all you need is to build a graph like this: Video Capture Source > Sample Grabber > Null Renderer. You set the sample grabber to redirect each frame to your implementation of `ISampleGrabberCB`, and in the `BufferCB` method you'll be provided with a pointer to the bitmap data of the frame. Here is some code that I tried to keep as short as possible thus sacrificing its robustness. Have a look but please don't leave it in production as is if it works.

```
class FrameGrabber : ISampleGrabberCB
{
    IMediaControl mediaCtrl;
    int width, height, stride;

    public FrameGrabber(DsDevice camDevice)
    {
        IFilterGraph2 filterGraph;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 graphBuilder;
        IBaseFilter camBase, nullRenderer;
        ISampleGrabber sampleGrabber;

        filterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;
        mediaCtrl = filterGraph as IMediaControl;

        graphBuilder = new CaptureGraphBuilder2() as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
        HRCheck(graphBuilder.SetFiltergraph(filterGraph));

        // Add camera
        HRCheck(filterGraph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(
            camDevice.Mon, null, camDevice.Name, out camBase));

        // Add sample grabber
        sampleGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;
        var mType = new AMMediaType()
        {
            majorType = MediaType.Video,
            subType = MediaSubType.RGB24,
            formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo
        };
        HRCheck(sampleGrabber.SetMediaType(mType));
        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(mType);
        HRCheck(sampleGrabber.SetCallback(this, 1));
        HRCheck(filterGraph.AddFilter(sampleGrabber as IBaseFilter, "CamGrabber"));

        // Add null renderer
        nullRenderer = new NullRenderer() as IBaseFilter;
        HRCheck(filterGraph.AddFilter(nullRenderer, "Null renderer"));

        // Render the webcam through the grabber and the renderer
        HRCheck(graphBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video,
            camBase, sampleGrabber as IBaseFilter, nullRenderer));

        // Get resulting picture size
        mType = new AMMediaType();
        HRCheck(sampleGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType(mType));
        if (mType.formatType != FormatType.VideoInfo || mType.formatPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown grabber media format");
        }
        var videoInfoHeader = Marshal.PtrToStructure(mType.formatPtr,
            typeof(VideoInfoHeader)) as VideoInfoHeader;
        width = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Width;
        height = videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.Height;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1}", width, height); 
        stride = width * (videoInfoHeader.BmiHeader.BitCount / 8);
        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(mType);

        HRCheck(mediaCtrl.Run());
    }

    public int BufferCB(double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BufferCB: " + SampleTime.ToString());
        // This is the bitmap of the frame but you may want
        // to copy it to some other memory location to
        // process/save/send it from there
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride,
                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pBuffer);
        return 0;
    }

    public int SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample)
    {
        // This won't be called because sampleGrabber.SetCallback(this, 1)
        // -- 1 means BufferCB
        return Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pSample);
    }

    static void HRCheck(int hr)
    {
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
```

And this is how you would call it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cam = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice).First();
        var grabber = new FrameGrabber(cam);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```